# How to backup/sync multiple separate sub-folders (ideally into one parent folder) in OwnCloud

Tags: owncloud

In OwnCloud, I would like to create a single folder, say "Jake", and then add two separate local folders into it, say "Pictures" and "Documents" (they are on different partitions locally).

How can I do that? 
It would already help if I could backup two folders, even without creating a common parent folder, but I have no idea how to do that. Some post point to 'unsyncing the root folder' (https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=16817 or [Sync different folders with OwnCloud](https://superuser.com/questions/447970/sync-different-folders-with-owncloud)), but I can't see how to do that. In the Desktop client, there is a "choose what to sync" menu, but it doesn't allow to unsync the root (it always remains checked or partially checked). I can also 'remove' the root folder in the client, but if I then create a new one, I still have the same problem.

So, how can I sync to separate folders in OwnCloud, ideally into a common parent folder?

Btw, I'm using OwnCloud 1.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be found here: https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=29949. Apparently you have to 'remove' the root folder (called 'ownCloud') in the client and then add your folders individually as subfolders to the remote root.